# Selecting rows from a Dataframe based on values in multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This question is *very* related to [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas), and I'll even use the example from the very helpful accepted solution on that question. Here's the example from the accepted solution (credit to unutbu):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo'.split(),
                   'B': 'one one two three two two one three'.split(),
                   'C': np.arange(8), 'D': np.arange(8) * 2})
print(df)
#      A      B  C   D
# 0  foo    one  0   0
# 1  bar    one  1   2
# 2  foo    two  2   4
# 3  bar  three  3   6
# 4  foo    two  4   8
# 5  bar    two  5  10
# 6  foo    one  6  12
# 7  foo  three  7  14

print(df.loc[df['A'] == 'foo'])
```

yields

```
     A      B  C   D
0  foo    one  0   0
2  foo    two  2   4
4  foo    two  4   8
6  foo    one  6  12
7  foo  three  7  14
```

But what if I want to pick out all rows that include both 'foo' and 'one'? Here that would be row 0 and 6. My attempt at it is to try

```
print(df.loc[df['A'] == 'foo' and df['B'] == 'one'])
```

This does not work, unfortunately. Can anybody suggest a way to implement something like this? Ideally it would be general enough that there could be a more complex set  of conditions in there involving `and` and `or`, though I don't actually need that for my purposes.

Comment: By the way, I've also linked this in a comment to the accepted solution on the original question so that others might find it also when accessing the original question.

Comment: `df.query("A=='foo' and B=='one'")` is another way

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is only a very small change needed in your code: change the `and` with `&` (and add parentheses for correct ordering of comparisons):

```
In [104]: df.loc[(df['A'] == 'foo') & (df['B'] == 'one')]
Out[104]:
     A    B  C   D
0  foo  one  0   0
6  foo  one  6  12
```

The reason you have to use `&` is that this will do the comparison element-wise on arrays, while `and` expect to compare two expressions that evaluate to True or False.
Similarly, when you want the `or` comparison, you can use `|` in this case.

Comment: Thanks @joris. I've come from Matlab and trained myself to use `and` and `or` instead of `&&` and `||` so it would have to be the case that what I'm trying to do requires something that looks more like my original Matlab thinking. In any case, I appreciate the explanation and that your answer works for assignment also.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with tiny altering in your code:

```
print(df[df['A'] == 'foo'][df['B'] == 'one'])
```

**Output:**

```
     A    B  C   D
0  foo  one  0   0
6  foo  one  6  12
```

Comment: Just note that as long as you are only selecting data this is OK, but once you want to assign a new value to such selection, this chained indexing will not work anymore. Therefore I would recommend to use `&` and index in one pass.

Comment: Thanks very much for this George. While both your answer and that of joris suffice for my purposes, I accepted joris' answer because he explains why `and` doesn't work and his answer allows assignment also. Still, I appreciate your suggestion and upticked it accordingly.

Comment: @Shane My pleasure Shane. Agree, he explained your case with and/&. By the way, I see this operand difference first too, so I learnt something new as well. So it's all right, and thanks for the uptick. :)