# vectorize percentile value of column B of column A (for groups)

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, apply, percentile

For every pair of `src` and `dest` airport cities I want to return a percentile of column `a` given a value of column `b`.

I can do this manually as such:

example df with only 2 pairs of src/dest (I have thousands in my actual df):

```
dt  src dest    a   b
0   2016-01-01  YYZ SFO 548.12  279.28
1   2016-01-01  DFW PDX 111.35  -65.50
2   2016-02-01  YYZ SFO 64.84   342.35
3   2016-02-01  DFW PDX 63.81   61.64
4   2016-03-01  YYZ SFO 614.29  262.83

{'a': {0: 548.12,
  1: 111.34999999999999,
  2: 64.840000000000003,
  3: 63.810000000000002,
  4: 614.28999999999996,
  5: -207.49000000000001,
  6: 151.31999999999999,
  7: -56.43,
  8: 611.37,
  9: -296.62,
  10: 6417.5699999999997,
  11: -376.25999999999999,
  12: 465.12,
  13: -821.73000000000002,
  14: 1270.6700000000001,
  15: -1410.0899999999999,
  16: 1312.6600000000001,
  17: -326.25999999999999,
  18: 1683.3699999999999,
  19: -24.440000000000001,
  20: 583.60000000000002,
  21: -5.2400000000000002,
  22: 1122.74,
  23: 195.21000000000001,
  24: 97.040000000000006,
  25: 133.94},
 'b': {0: 279.27999999999997,
  1: -65.5,
  2: 342.35000000000002,
  3: 61.640000000000001,
  4: 262.82999999999998,
  5: 115.89,
  6: 268.63999999999999,
  7: 2.3500000000000001,
  8: 91.849999999999994,
  9: 62.119999999999997,
  10: 778.33000000000004,
  11: -142.78,
  12: 1675.53,
  13: -214.36000000000001,
  14: 983.80999999999995,
  15: -207.62,
  16: 632.13999999999999,
  17: -132.53,
  18: 422.36000000000001,
  19: 13.470000000000001,
  20: 642.73000000000002,
  21: -144.59999999999999,
  22: 213.15000000000001,
  23: -50.200000000000003,
  24: 338.27999999999997,
  25: -129.69},
 'dest': {0: 'SFO',
  1: 'PDX',
  2: 'SFO',
  3: 'PDX',
  4: 'SFO',
  5: 'PDX',
  6: 'SFO',
  7: 'PDX',
  8: 'SFO',
  9: 'PDX',
  10: 'SFO',
  11: 'PDX',
  12: 'SFO',
  13: 'PDX',
  14: 'SFO',
  15: 'PDX',
  16: 'SFO',
  17: 'PDX',
  18: 'SFO',
  19: 'PDX',
  20: 'SFO',
  21: 'PDX',
  22: 'SFO',
  23: 'PDX',
  24: 'SFO',
  25: 'PDX'},
 'dt': {0: Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2016-02-01 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2016-02-01 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2016-03-01 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2016-03-01 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2016-04-01 00:00:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2016-04-01 00:00:00'),
  8: Timestamp('2016-05-01 00:00:00'),
  9: Timestamp('2016-05-01 00:00:00'),
  10: Timestamp('2016-06-01 00:00:00'),
  11: Timestamp('2016-06-01 00:00:00'),
  12: Timestamp('2016-07-01 00:00:00'),
  13: Timestamp('2016-07-01 00:00:00'),
  14: Timestamp('2016-08-01 00:00:00'),
  15: Timestamp('2016-08-01 00:00:00'),
  16: Timestamp('2016-09-01 00:00:00'),
  17: Timestamp('2016-09-01 00:00:00'),
  18: Timestamp('2016-10-01 00:00:00'),
  19: Timestamp('2016-10-01 00:00:00'),
  20: Timestamp('2016-11-01 00:00:00'),
  21: Timestamp('2016-11-01 00:00:00'),
  22: Timestamp('2016-12-01 00:00:00'),
  23: Timestamp('2016-12-01 00:00:00'),
  24: Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'),
  25: Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00')},
 'src': {0: 'YYZ',
  1: 'DFW',
  2: 'YYZ',
  3: 'DFW',
  4: 'YYZ',
  5: 'DFW',
  6: 'YYZ',
  7: 'DFW',
  8: 'YYZ',
  9: 'DFW',
  10: 'YYZ',
  11: 'DFW',
  12: 'YYZ',
  13: 'DFW',
  14: 'YYZ',
  15: 'DFW',
  16: 'YYZ',
  17: 'DFW',
  18: 'YYZ',
  19: 'DFW',
  20: 'YYZ',
  21: 'DFW',
  22: 'YYZ',
  23: 'DFW',
  24: 'YYZ',
  25: 'DFW'}}
```

I want the percentile per group of `src` and `dest` pairs. So there should only be 1 percentile value for each pair. I only want to perform the percentile given `b` where `date = 2017-01-01` for each `src` and `dest` pair over the entire column `a` for each pair. Make sense?

I can do this manually for example for a specific pair `i.e. src=YYZ and dest=SFT`:

```
from scipy import stats
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

p0 = dt.datetime(2017,1,1)

# lets slice df for src=YYZ and dest = SFO
x = df[(df.src =='YYZ') &
(df.dest =='SFO') &
(df.dt ==p0)].b.values[0]

# given B, what percentile does it fall in for the entire column A for YYZ, SFO
stats.percentileofscore(df['a'],x)
61.53846153846154
```

In the above case, I did this manually for pairs YYZ and SFO. However, I have thousands of pairs in my df.

How do I `vectorize` this using `pandas features` rather than looping through every pair?

There must be a way to use `groupby` and use `apply` over a function?

My desired df should look something like:

```
    src dest  percentile
0   YYZ SFO   61.54
1   DFW PDX   23.07
2   XXX YYY   blahblah1
3   AAA BBB   blahblah2
...
```

**UPDATE:**

I implemented the following:

```
def b_percentile_a(df,x,y,b):
    z = df[(df['src'] == x ) & (df['dest'] == y)].a
    r = stats.percentileofscore(z,b)
    return r

b_vector_df = df[df.dt == p0]

b_vector_df['p0_a_percentile_b'] = \
    b_vector_df.apply(lambda x: b_percentile_a(df,x.src,x.dest,x.b), axis=1)
```

It takes `5.16` seconds for `100` pairs. I have `55,000` pairs. So this will take `~50` minutes. I need to run this `36` times so its going to take `several days` of run time.

There must be a faster approach?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas on how to implement the above for each src/dest group using `pandas` features in as few lines of code as possible that don't require manual looping?

Comment: In your example calculation for a specific pair, you compute the percentile of your target value relative to *all* values of `df.a`.  Is that what you want?  Your description seems to indicate you want to calculate the percentile of the target value relative to only the rows of `df` with a particular `src` and `dest`, but that's not what your code actually does.  Because of that, it gives a different result than the `b_percentile_a` function you give at the end.

Comment: Also, if performance is your concern, it would be good to have a realistic sample data set to benchmark on.  The performance of different solutions may vary depending on the nature of the data (e.g., how large each src/dest block is).

Comment: Just to understand better: by 55,000 pairs, do you mean the dataframe has 55,000 entries, or do you actually have 55,000 different combinations of src and dest (and therefore many more rows in the dataframe)?

Comment: @BrenBarn - I want `to calculate the percentile of the target value relative to only the rows of df with a particular src and dest`. All df.a values for each src/dest pair. I believe my code at the bottom should do just that (but its very slow). i.e. `b_percentile_a()`

Comment: @JARS - I have 55,000 different combinations of src and dest. So yes, many more rows in the dataframe. Typically each src/dest pair has 12 rows so 55,000 x 12 is approx size.

Comment: How are needs the `b_vector_df = df[df.dt == p0]` attention? You don't mentioned this in the explanation to #BrenBarn. As I understand it right, `a` and `b` have typically a size of 12 per Pair. And the percentile have to be computed between these 12 values.

Comment: @stovfl - you are right. I should have been more clear. So it is the value of `b` when `df[df.dt == p0]` for each `src/dest` pair that is to be percentiled over the entire 12 values of `a` for each pair. Make sense?

Answer (score 6):

**Obtained a incredible saving of time!**

**Output:**
Size of a_list: 49998 Randomized unique values
**percentile_1 (Your given df - scipy)**
computed percentile 104 times - 104 records in 0:00:07.777022

**percentile_9 (class PercentileOfScore(rank_searchsorted_list) using given df)**
computed percentile 104 times - 104 records in 0:00:00.000609
`_    dt       src dest    a       b             pct           scipy   _
 0: 2016-01-01 YYZ SFO   54812  279.28  74.81299251970079  74.8129925197
 1: 2016-01-01 DFW PDX  111.35  -65.5   24.66698667946718  24.6669866795
 2: 2016-02-01 YYZ SFO   64.84  342.35  76.4810592423697   76.4810592424
 3: 2016-02-01 DFW PDX   63.81   61.64  63.84655386215449  63.8465538622
...
24: 2017-01-01 YYZ SFO   97.04  338.28  76.3570542821712   76.3570542822
25: 2017-01-01 DFW PDX  133.94 -129.69  21.4668586743469   21.4668586743`

Looking at the implementation of `scipy.percentileofscore` i found that the whole `list( a )`
are - copied, inserted, sorted, searched - on every call of `percentileofscore`.

I implemented my own `class PercentileOfScore`

```
import numpy as np
class PercentileOfScore(object):

    def __init__(self, aList):
        self.a = np.array( aList )
        self.a.sort()
        self.n = float(len(self.a))
        self.pct = self.__rank_searchsorted_list
    # end def __init__

    def __rank_searchsorted_list(self, score_list):
        adx = np.searchsorted(self.a, score_list, side='right')
        pct = []
        for idx in adx:
            # Python 2.x needs explicit type casting float(int)
            pct.append( (float(idx) / self.n) * 100.0 )

        return pct
    # end def _rank_searchsorted_list
# end class PercentileOfScore
```

---

I don't think that `def percentile_7` will fit your needs. `dt` will not considered.

```
PctOS = None
def percentile_7(df_flat):
    global PctOS
    result = {}
    for k in df_flat.pair_dict.keys():
        # df_flat.pair_dict = { 'src.dst': [b,b,...bn] }
        result[k] = PctOS.pct( df_flat.pair_dict[k] )

    return result
# end def percentile_7
```

---

In your manual sample you use the whole `df.a`. In this sample its `dt_flat.a_list`, but i'm not sure if this is what you want?

```
from PercentileData import DF_flat
def main():
    # DF_flat.data = {'dt.src.dest':[a,b]}
    df_flat = DF_flat()

    # Instantiate Global PctOS
    global PctOS
    # df_flat.a_list = [a,a,...an]
    PctOS = PercentileOfScore(df_flat.a_list)

    result = percentile_7(df_flat)
    # result = dict{'src.dst':[pct,pct...pctn]}
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 and 2.7.9  - numpy: 1.8.2***

Comment: that seems amazing. Can you please share the code for `percentile_7` and your `class PercentileOfScore`?

Comment: Would this work for python 2 as well? Aside from the basic syntax differences like print and print()?

Comment: @AsheKetchum Tested with Python 2.7.9, have to add explicit type casting float(int). Edited the Answer. Python 2.7.9 can handle print() as well.

Comment: Why do we need the `for idx in adx:` loop. Instead, we could do `pct = ads / self.n * 100.0` to vectorize the division, right?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have a list of pairs, say `pairs = [[a,b], [c,d], ...]` and df is defined,

```
    r = stats.percentileofscore(z,b)
    return r

for pair in pairs:
    # get the corresponding rows for each pair
    bvalues = df.loc[(df['src']==pair[0])&(df['dest']==pair[1])][['a', 'b']]
    # apply the percentileofscore map
    b_vector_df['p0_a_percentile_b'] = bvalues.b.apply(lambda x: stats.percentileofscore(bvalues.a, x))
```

I am not entirely sure what the goal is. My understanding is you read a **b** value for each **src**, **dest** pair and look for the corresponding **a** value and then calculate the percentile of that **a** value. Let me know if this helps :)

**EDIT**: assuming you are only working with the five columns `date, src, dest, a, and b`, you can consider working with a copy of the data frame that only contains those 5 columns. It reduces the amount of work required by each extraction step. I feel like it is more efficient to work with only the amount of data you need. 
[Selecting rows from a Dataframe based on values in multiple columns in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31756340/selecting-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-multiple-columns-in-pandas?noredirect=1&lq=1) is a discussion that may be relevant for you.

Answer (score 4):

You can groupby multiple columns at once.

```
# takes the b value at a specified point
# and returns its percentile of the full a array
def b_pct(df, p0):
    bval = df.b[df.dt==p0]
    assert bval.size == 1, 'can have only one entry per timestamp'
    bval = bval.values[0]
    # compute the percentile
    return (df.a < bval).sum() / len(df.a)

# splits the full dataframe up into groups by (src, dest) trajectory and
# returns a dataframe of the form src, dest, percentile
def trajectory_b_percentile(df, p0):
    percentile_df = pd.DataFrame([pd.Series([s, d, b_pct(g, p0)],
                                            index=['src', 'dest', 'percentile'])
                                  for ((s, d), g) in df.groupby(('src', 'dest'))])
    return percentile_df
```

For comparison, your code above spits out

```
           dt  src dest       a       b  p0_a_percentile_b
24 2017-01-01  YYZ  SFO   97.04  338.28          23.076923
25 2017-01-01  DFW  PDX  133.94 -129.69          46.153846
```

whereas `trajectory_b_percentile' returns

```
   src dest  percentile
0  DFW  PDX   46.1538
1  YYZ  SFO   23.0769
```

I didn't see any speedup with 25 entries, but it should be noticeable with more.

Answer (score 1):

It seems another considerable speedup is obtained by converting everything to numpy arrays and constructing the percentiles also as a numpy array:

```
# Get airport strings as indices
_, ir = np.unique(df['src'].values,  return_inverse=True)
_, ic = np.unique(df['dest'].values, return_inverse=True)

# Get a and b columns
a = df['a'].values
b = df['b'].values

# Compute percentile scores in a numpy array
prc = np.zeros(a.shape)
for i in range(0, a.shape[0]):
    prc[i] = stats.percentileofscore(a[np.logical_and(ir==ir[i], ic==ic[i])], b[i])
```

On a dataframe with 24000 entries (see construction below), running `%%timeit` gives

```
1 loop, best of 3: 2.17 s per loop
```

However, the original version

```
df['p0_a_percentile_b'] = \
df.apply(lambda x: b_percentile_a(df,x.src,x.dest,x.b), axis=1)
```

yields

```
1 loop, best of 3: 1min 2s per loop
```

which is much slower. I also checked that both snippets produce the same output by running `np.all(prc == df.p0_a_percentile_b.values)`, yielding `True`.

## Appendix:

I constructed a dataframe to test this and here I share the process for reproducibility. I took 2000 pairs of airports using 100 unique airport names, then generated 12 dataframe rows per pair, and then generated random a and b columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy.matlib as mat

# Construct dataframe

T=12
N_airports = 100
N_entries = 2000
airports = np.arange(0, N_airports).astype('string')

src  = mat.repmat(airports[np.random.randint(N_airports, size=(N_entries, ))], 1, T)
dest = mat.repmat(airports[np.random.randint(N_airports, size=(N_entries, ))], 1, T)
a    = np.random.uniform(size=N_entries*T)
b    = np.random.uniform(size=N_entries*T)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((src, dest, a, b)).T, columns=['src', 'dest', 'a', 'b'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Please verify and comment if this represent your Data Model!

1. 6 ^ 6 Pairs [AAA-ZZZ] = 46,656 are used. 
   Typically each *PAIR* has 12 *RECORDS*
2. This is *RECORD*( 0 ) of *PAIR*( DFW PDX )

   > ```
   >    dt        src dest       a           b
   > 0: 2016-01-01 DFW PDX   111.35       -65.5
   > ```
3. This is *SET*( DFW PDX ) = 13 RECORDS of *PAIR*( DFW PDX )

   > ```
   >    dt        src dest       a           b
   > 0: 2016-01-01 DFW PDX   111.35       -65.5
   > 1: 2016-02-01 DFW PDX    63.81       61.64
   > 2: 2016-03-01 DFW PDX  -207.49      115.89
   > 3: 2016-04-01 DFW PDX   -56.43        2.35
   > 4: 2016-05-01 DFW PDX  -296.62       62.12
   > 5: 2016-06-01 DFW PDX  -376.26     -142.78
   > 6: 2016-07-01 DFW PDX  -821.73     -214.36
   > 7: 2016-08-01 DFW PDX -1410.09     -207.62
   > 8: 2016-09-01 DFW PDX  -326.26     -132.53
   > 9: 2016-10-01 DFW PDX   -24.44       13.47
   > 10:2016-11-01 DFW PDX    -5.24      -144.6
   > 11:2016-12-01 DFW PDX   195.21       -50.2
   > 12:2017-01-01 DFW PDX   133.94     -129.69
   > ```
4. Example: Calculate Percentile of *RECORD*( 0 )

   > ```
   >    dt        src dest       a           b
   > 0: 2016-01-01 DFW PDX   111.35       -65.5
   > ```
   >
   > *Pseudocode:* 
   >     stats.percentileofscore( SET( DFW PDX )[a0...a12], -65.5) = 46.15
5. Example: Calculate Percentile of *SET*( DFW PDX )

   > *Pseudocode*
   >       for record in SET( DFW PDX ):
   >          stats.percentileofscore( SET( DFW PDX )[a0...a12], record.b)
   >      Output: pct0...pct12
   >
   > Using rank_searchsorted_list does not require *'for record in'* :
   >       rank_searchsorted_list( SET( DFW PDX )[a0...a12], SET( DFW PDX )[b0...b12] )
   >      Output: [pct0...pct12]
6. This is *SET*( DFW PDX ) vectorized

   ```
   OBJECT = {'DFW PDX':[
   ['2016-01-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-03-01', '2016-04-01', '2016-05-01', '2016-06-01', '2016-07-01', '2016-08-01', '2016-09-01', '2016-10-01', '2016-11-01', '2016-12-01', '2017-01-01']
   [111.35, 63.81, -207.49, -56.43, -296.62, -376.26, -821.73, -1410.09, -326.26, -24.44, -5.24, 195.21, 133.94]
   [-65.5, 61.64, 115.89, 2.35, 62.12, -142.78, -214.36, -207.62, -132.53, 13.47, -144.6, -50.2, -129.69]
   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
   ]}
   ```
7. Example: Calculate Percentile of *OBJECT*( DFW PDX )
   Using *stats.percentileofscore*:

   ```
   a = 1; b = 2
   for b_value in OBJECT['DFW PDX'][b]:
       stats.percentileofscore( OBJECT['DFW PDX'][a], b_value)
   Output: pct0...pct12
   ```

   Using *rank_searchsorted_list* does not require *'for b_value in'*:

   ```
   a = 1; b = 2; pct = 3
   vector = OBJECT['DFW PDX']
   vector[pct] = rank_searchsorted_list( vector[a], vector[b] )
   ```

   Output:

   > ```
   >    dt         src dest      a           b       pct    scipy
   > 0: 2016-01-01 DFW PDX   111.35       -65.5     46.15   46.15
   > 1: 2016-02-01 DFW PDX    63.81       61.64     69.23   69.23
   > 2: 2016-03-01 DFW PDX  -207.49      115.89     84.61   84.61
   > 3: 2016-04-01 DFW PDX   -56.43        2.35     69.23   69.23
   > 4: 2016-05-01 DFW PDX  -296.62       62.12     69.23   69.23
   > 5: 2016-06-01 DFW PDX  -376.26     -142.78     46.15   46.15
   > 6: 2016-07-01 DFW PDX  -821.73     -214.36     38.46   38.46
   > 7: 2016-08-01 DFW PDX -1410.09     -207.62     38.46   38.46
   > 8: 2016-09-01 DFW PDX  -326.26     -132.53     46.15   46.15
   > 9: 2016-10-01 DFW PDX   -24.44       13.47     69.23   69.23
   > 10:2016-11-01 DFW PDX    -5.24      -144.6     46.15   46.15
   > 11:2016-12-01 DFW PDX   195.21       -50.2     53.84   53.84
   > 12:2017-01-01 DFW PDX   133.94     -129.69     46.15   46.15
   > ```

Please verify and confirm the calculated percentile!