# Selecting rows from a Dataframe based on values from multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This question is *very* related to these two questions [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas) and [thisone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31756340/selecting-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-multiple-columns-in-pandas), and I'll even use the example from the very helpful accepted solution on that question. Here's the example from the accepted solution (credit to unutbu):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo'.split(),
                   'B': 'one one two three two two one three'.split(),
                   'C': np.arange(8), 'D': np.arange(8) * 2})
print(df)
#      A      B  C   D
# 0  foo    one  0   0
# 1  bar    one  1   2
# 2  foo    two  2   4
# 3  bar  three  3   6
# 4  foo    two  4   8
# 5  bar    two  5  10
# 6  foo    one  6  12
# 7  foo  three  7  14

print(df.loc[df['A'] == 'foo'])
```

yields

```
     A      B  C   D
0  foo    one  0   0
2  foo    two  2   4
4  foo    two  4   8
6  foo    one  6  12
7  foo  three  7  14
```

But  I want to have all rows of A and only the arrows in B that have 'two' in them. My attempt at it is to try

```
print(df.loc[df['A']) & df['B'] == 'two'])
```

This does not work, unfortunately. Can anybody suggest a way to implement something like this? it would be of a great help if the solution is somewhat general where for example column A doesn't have the same value which is 'foo' but has different values and you still want the whole column.

Comment: If you dont want to filter on A, then simply dont include any condition on this column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* I understand your modified question. After sub-selecting on a condition of `B`, then you can select the columns you want, such as:

```
In [1]: df.loc[df.B =='two'][['A', 'B']]
Out[1]: 
     A    B
2  foo  two
4  foo  two
5  bar  two
```

For example, if I wanted to concatenate all the string of column A, for which column B had value `'two'`, then I could do:

```
In [2]: df.loc[df.B =='two'].A.sum()  # <-- use .mean() for your quarterly data
Out[2]: 'foofoobar'
```

You could also `groupby` the values of column B and get such a concatenation result for every different B-group from one expression:

```
In [3]: df.groupby('B').apply(lambda x: x.A.sum())
Out[3]: 
B
one      foobarfoo
three       barfoo
two      foofoobar
dtype: object
```

To filter on `A` *and* `B` use [`numpy.logical_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html):

```
In [1]: df.loc[np.logical_and(df.A == 'foo', df.B == 'two')]
Out[1]: 
     A    B  C  D
2  foo  two  2  4
4  foo  two  4  8
```

Comment: sorry but i edited what i asked, i want to have the whole column A and not only foo so in the case the one with index 5 should also be included but it should assume that i don't know what the column has i just want it all.

Comment: @AbdulMalekAltawekji Your question is not clear. What do you mean that you want "the whole column of A", but "only rows of B that have 'two' in them"? Those two conditions don't seem compatible.

Comment: sorry for the inclarity. i meant i want to not only foo in column A but if there was in column A a boo and a gee as well which also has the value 'two' in the column B, i would also like to have them displayed but without assuming that i know that the column A has a boo and a gee as well. So as long as it's in A and in B it has a 'two', i want it.

Comment: So do you mean you just want to filter on `B`, but then choose columns A and B after filtering? I'll add an update.

Comment: Maybe it's easier to explain what i'm personally trying to achieve, i have a huge dataset with information about movies. I have a column that is called midweekGains which has numerical values about gains during of the midweek of the movies. I also have a column that is called 'quarter' which is about which quarter of the year the film was published which has 4 values, 1,2,3 and 4 so i'm trying to calculate the mean of the midweekGains of the films in quarter 1 for instance.

Comment: Yes, then you don't care about filtering on `midweekGain` at all. You *only* care about filtering on `quarter` and then doing regular averaging afterwards. In other words, you don't need anything like `df['A']` in your question. You *only* need `df['quarter'] == 1`.

Comment: oh sorry for not noticing that. As someone who just started with this, i figured out that i didn't understand it correctly. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165796/discussion-between-abdul-malek-altawekji-and-ely).

Answer (score 7):

Easy , if you do

```
     df[['A','B']][df['B']=='two']
```

you will get:

```
    A    B

2  foo  two
4  foo  two
5  bar  two
```

To filter on both A and B:

```
    df[['A','B']][(df['B']=='two') & (df['A']=='foo')]
```

You get:

```
        A    B
    2  foo  two
    4  foo  two
```

and if you want all the columns :

```
        df[df['B']=='two']
```

you will get:

```
            A    B  C   D
        2  foo  two  2   4
        4  foo  two  4   8
        5  bar  two  5  10
```

Answer (score 3):

Row subsetting: Isn't this you are looking for ?

```
df.loc[(df['A'] == 'foo') & (df['B'] == 'two')]

   A   B  C D
2 foo two 2 4
4 foo two 4 8
```

You can also add `.reset_index()` at the end to initialize indexes from zero.